# How to solve this question on integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let f:[$\frac{1}{2}$,1]$\to$$R$ be a positive,non constant and differentiable function such that $f'(x)<2f(x)$ and $f(\frac{1}{2})=1$.then find value of definite integral in interval of $\frac{1}{2}$ to 1 for  $f(x)$ in which it lies. I dont know how to convert thewords into integral so i wrote it in my way.how can i solve that? I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

All I can get from your sentence is the following :

Since $f(x)\gt\frac 12 f^\prime (x)$, 
$$\int_{0.5}^1f(x)dx\gt\frac 12\int_{0.5}^1f^\prime(x)dx=\frac 12\left[f(x)\right]_{0.5}^1=\frac{1}{2}(f(1)-1).$$

By David H's comment, we can have an upper bound on the integral. I'm going to add details to his comment.

Since $f(x)$ is positive, we have $2\gt\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f(x)}$. Hence, 
$$\int_{0.5}^{x}2dx\gt\int_{0.5}^{x}\frac{f^\prime (x)}{f(x)}dx\Rightarrow 2x-1\gt \ln f(x)\Rightarrow f(x)\lt e^{2x-1}.$$

Hence, 
$$\int_{0.5}^{1}f(x)dx\lt \int_{0.5}^{1}e^{2x-1}=\frac 12(e-1).$$

As a result, we have
$$\frac{1}{2}(f(1)-1)\lt \int_{0.5}^{1}f(x)dx\lt \frac 12(e-1).$$

Comment: To get an upper bound on the integral, divide both sides of the inequality by $f$, which we can do since it is positive, and integrate from 1/2 to x, and now re-solve the inequality for $f$ to get: $f(x)<e^{2x-1}$. Now integrate from 1/2 to 1 for the upper bound $\int_{\frac12}^1f(x)dx<\frac12(e-1)$.

Comment: @DavidH: Nice idea! I didn't notice it.

Comment: No prob. I'm stumped as to whether or not $f(1)$ is somehow determined as well by some witchery. We know $0<f(1)<e$...